# how to write css for the text which doesn't have any tag, just br tag and text

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I am rendering some html in asp.net mvc and the raw html like

```
this is text
<br/>
this is another text.
```

What I am looking for is use float on both and give them 50% width so they use 50% of available width. I have full control to use anything in jquery, css to do this.

I am trying to something like `$(".check-form.txt br").before()` I am trying to select the text before br tag and after br tag.

does anyone have idea for this.

If there is no way to do this I thing I should better wrap them in p tag. Does anyone have idea how to wrap them in p tag. I means first line in a p tag and second in another p tag and use some jquery/css magic to float both of them to left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, your html is mostly in a element, try to look in chrome inspector(f12) to see in wich elements you text is comming, then write your css for that... or just put your text in a  .

Comment: it's inside a div, how I can select the text before br and after br. I am thinking to wrap them in a p tag, any idea to group them and wrap them in jquery

Comment: but why with jquery ? do it just with html, you're making it very hard for yourself

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<span class="your classes">content</span>` tag.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.